# Using Re package in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a webpage and using BeautifulSoup and selenium. The webpage provides a live temperature, and when I parse it I am able to get said data. But it gets stored in a list. See code below:

```
pls = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtDisplay"]').text
print(pls)

print(list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pls))))
tempInFar = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pls)))

if tempInFar >= 80:                            # ***** error comes from here *******
    print("1:temp:"+str(tempInFar))
else:
    print("0:temp:"+str(tempInFar)+"\n\n")
```

The if-statement yields the following error:

`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

The first block prints give me the following:

```
__________________________

System Cooling
67F
__________________________

[67]                                         # Parsed data
1                                            # Length of parsed data
```

The parsed data is the `[67]` and I just need its value.

Here is the entirety of the code:

```
import time
import re
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input("Enter IP:  ")
urlpage = "http://" + url 

print("Parsing Temperature Data from: " + urlpage)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(2)

page = requests.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

pls = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtDisplay"]').text
print(pls)

print(list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pls))))
tempInFar = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pls)))

print(len(tempInFar))

if tempInFar >= 80:                            # len() is a no go, reports binanry answer
    print("1:temp:"+str(tempInFar))
else:
    print("0:temp:"+str(tempInFar)+"\n\n")
```

In the if-statement I've tried using `if len(tempinFar) >= 80: ...` unfortunately it doesn't return the data I would like it to.

I am expecting the parsed information with the input of `67` to give the output of: `0:temp:67`

The same goes if the input were `90` I am expecting the the output of: `1:temp:90`

I am looking for some guidance if anyone is willing to help me out.

Here is the most up to date code. It works, well kind of. It runs without error, but when comparing the strings my parsed string is somehow bigger than the string that it is being compared to. Which is false. For example, parsed data is `70`. My if statement is telling me that `70 >= 100` which is not true so it should print the line in the else-statement.

code:

```
import time
import re
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input("Enter IP:  ")
urlpage = "http://" + url 

print("Parsing Temperature Data from: " + urlpage)
# run chrome webdriver from executable path of your choice
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(2)

page = requests.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")


pls = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtDisplay"]').text


#tempInFar = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+\n\n', pls)))
tempInFar = re.search(r'\d+', pls)


if tempInFar[0] >= str(100):                            # comparing as str because parsed value is a str
    print("1:temp:"+str(tempInFar[0]))
else:
    print("0:temp:"+str(tempInFar[0])+"\n\n")

print(tempInFar[0])                                     # checking parsed data
print(type(tempInFar[0]))                               # making sure parsed data is string
print(str(100))                                         # test
```

After the code successfully runs I get the following output:

```
1:temp:70
70
<class 'str'>
100
```

This should print `0:temp70` but doesn't. I even test printed the parsed data and the comparator.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You have a list, you want the first element of the list, so `tempInFar[0]` ?

Comment: Or don't use `re.findall()` if you just want the first match, use `re.search()`

Comment: @Barmar Using re.search() as  `tempInFar = re.search(r'\d+', pls)`  gives me a new error: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 're.Match' and 'int'`

Comment: @teapot418 doing this way `if tempInFar[0] >= 80:...` i get the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It's not a drop-in replacement. You have to change the code to extract the results properly from the match results.

Comment: Read a tutorial on how to use `re.search()`, I'm not going to try to teach you in comments here.

Comment: You're misunderstanding several things in the course of your explanation. Pointing out each instance would be quite a chore and user Barmar is not wrong about the comment section not being the right place to teach you the basics of Python. Look more closely at the result you're getting and try to understand what *type* the data it returns is, and whether it perhaps does contain the result you need, you just need to learn how to access parts of the data structure you received. As others have indicated, there may also be more direct ways to get just what you need.

Comment: @Grismar I understand, i will look more into everything that everyone has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue, not that it matters now that this posting has negative reviews. I doubt it'll reach those with the same problem I had. But it was a simple fix off of my updated code.

However, the correction I made, I had tried in the past and it was returning an error. Given that some other changes were not made yet. Which is why I didn't try the solution that I have.

---

I'd also like to note that I was researching all the materials that I was using, I wasn't looking for an answer on here. Rather I was looking for help/guidance. Which I stated in my initial post. So before making assumptions think worst case and ask, please.

---

**The short answer:**

I was comparing strings not integers.

---

Previously I tried the following:

```
if int(tempInFar) >= 100: ...
```

Giving the error:
`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 're.Match'`

Which lead me to make the arguments as `tempInFar >= str(100)` and resulting in my posting.

---

I came to find out that `int()` **cannot** make an *entire* list an integer. But you are able to take one element at a time from the list and make it an integer. In my case, I only needed the first item in the list. If you do need more than one element, use a for-loop to get each element and make them individual integers.

Resulting the correct arguments,

```
if int(tempInFar[0]) >= 100:                            # made element of list an int() because parsed value is a str
    print("\n1:temp:"+str(tempInFar[0])+"\n")
else:
    print("0:temp:"+str(tempInFar[0])+"\n\n")
```

I was able to achieve my end goal.

---

If I have to, I can post the entirety of the code. But I feel with the new information and my previous code, the new code should be derivable.